# System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries 101

Tags: governorlimits

> System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries 101

I am getting this error on below line

```
List <Call_Report_Attendees__c> cra =  [Select id, 
currencyIsoCode,Call_Report__c from Call_Report_Attendees__c where Call_Report__c 
in:setAttendeeId];
```

Please help me remove this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the governor limits. I guess you are using the line inside a for loop.

```
List cra = [Select id, currencyIsoCode,Call_Report__c from Call_Report_Attendees__c where Call_Report__c in:setAttendeeId];
```

Try using this line outside the loop if you are currently using inside any loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the Governor limit thats why error has been thrown.Please refer this post
 [I am getting this error: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/i-am-getting-this-error-system-limitexception-too-many-soql-queries-101)

And refer to the best practices for avoiding SOQL queries 101 error.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=System-LimitException-Too-many-SOQL-queries-101&language=en_US
Thanks.